# Django custom validation error for unchanged form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a `form` that has three `CharField`s. It gets loaded with an existing object. I am trying to write a custom `validation` that will return a 'No changes made' `error`if a user tries to submit the `form` without making any changes. Is there a way to compare initial form and updated form without going through each field? Something like:

```
form = Form(instance=id)
if request.POST.form == form:
    raise ValidationError(
        _('No changes made to name.'),
        code: 'No_changes'
    )
```

Comment: Is your form a `ModelForm`?

Comment: Yes.  From what I've been reading, i need to use `.has_changed` and `.add_error` somewhere. Still trying to figure the details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was actually simple to add this to my view:

```
if request.POST:
    name_form = NameForm(data=request.POST, instance=name)
    if name_form.has_changed() == False:
        name_form.add_error(None, _('No changes made.'))
    if name_form.is_valid():
        name_form.save()
```

Putting `None` in the `.add_error()` makes it a `non-field error`. If you wanted to make an error for a specific `field` you would put the name of the field there.

Answer (score 0):

When user submits the form it will save in DB at first.
So, rather than comparing forms, what you can do is override `save` or `_post_clean()` and write these validations.

```
def __post_clean(self):
  # fetch from db the existing values and compare 
  # if matches
  #  self.add_error('field_name','No changes made.')
```

This can also be done front-end side using JS (before submitting if values in fields have changed.)